# Boost python, compare raw pointer to managed pointer?

Tags: c++, python, boost

So I have an `std::map<KeyType, std::shared_ptr<ValueType>>` exposed up to python using `map_indexing_suite`.

In other places in the code I store references to the `ValueType` objects in the map using raw pointers, `ValueType*`, because those containers don't own the `ValueType` objects, the map does.

My question is, how can I expose the raw pointer to python in a way it can compare that reference to the shared pointer? Something like this:

```
valueRef = getRawReference()
for x in myMap:
    if x.data() == valueRef:
        print "match"
```

Comment: In C++, it would be `&*`. `*` turns a shared pointer into a reference to the object it points to. `&` turns a reference into the address of the object it refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

First define two methods:

```
bool eq(std::shared_ptr<ValueType> lhs, ValueType* rhs)
{
    return lhs.get() == rhs;
}

bool neq(std::shared_ptr<ValueType> lhs, ValueType* rhs)
{
    return lhs.get() != rhs;
}
```

Then in your BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE:

```
bp::def("getRawReference", getRawReference, bp::return_value_policy<bp::reference_existing_object>())

bp::class_<ValueType, std::shared_ptr<ValueType>>("ValueType")
    .def("__eq__", eq)
    .def("__neq__", neq);
```

Comment: `__neq__` should probably be `__ne__`