# Boost.Python: how to create & return a list of existing c++ objects, no copying

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

I'm using Boost.Python to expose an array of objects within another class:

```
class Thing {
  int i; // and of course other stuff
};

class Container {
  Thing *things[128];
  int n_things;
}
```

I'd like to provide to python a read-only list interface to the Things.  I have something like this in my boost.python extension source code:

```
static bp::list EXTget_things(Container &c)
{
  bp::list thing_list;
  for (int i = 0; i < c.n_things; i++) {
    thing_list.append(c.things[i]);
  }
  return thing_list;
}
```

I also have the (unusual?) constraint that I can't copy the Thing objects.  They don't have a working copy constructor, and I can't really change that.  I'd like to just return a python list containing the addresses of the original objects, and correspondingly ensure that python doesn't free the originals when it frees the list.

How can I do that?  (Or can it be done?)  I recognize it could cause lifetime problems if the Container goes out of scope in python, but some other python code still tries to use the param_list (since it has pointers into the Collection object), but I'm willing to work with that restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to expose both classes:

```
class_<Thing>("thing")
    .def_readwrite("i", &Thing::i)
;

class_<Container>("container")
    .def_readwrite("n_things", &Container::n_things)
;
```

and then create a method that returns a reference to the Thing:

```
Thing& get_thing(Container& c, size_t index)
{
    return *c.things[index];
}
```

finally, you should expose this function:

```
def("get_thing", get_thing, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>());
```

and than you can iterate over it:

```
c = mylib.container()
for i in xrange(c.n_things):
    thing = get_thing(c, i)
    thing.i = <INT_VALUE>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm hoping for something more pythonic with a list interface.

Comment: @GaryO OK, but notice that you can change it into a python list very easily: l = [get_thing(c, i) for i in xrange(c.n_things)]

Comment: I tried this, and it basically works, but if I try `get_thing(c, i)==get_thing(c, i)` it returns False.  Shouldn't it be returning a reference to the existing object and thus return True?

Comment: @GaryO it's because they aren't the same object, boost::python uses a trick to return the reference to the object, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/reference_existing_object.html (see the explanation and take a look into the last example)

Comment: In order to compare the objects, you should implement the operator __eq__, as pointed out here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612218/boost-python-compare-raw-pointer-to-managed-pointer] by @grivescorbett. (but you should compare two pointers instead of a shared_ptr and a pointer).